# Zero-width space affecting styling

Tags: css, sublimetext2

Just spent a piss-me-off amount of time running down this bug and am hoping someone has an answer as to what's causing it so I can hopefully never deal with it again.

I'm writing raw CSS for a site I'm building and am using psuedo-elements to add upward and downward pointing chevrons to the top and bottom, respectively, of some of the pages.

```css
#chevronUp {
  position: fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:5%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100px;
}
#chevronDown {
  position: fixed;
  left:50%;
  bottom:5%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index:10;
}

#chevronUp:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #3c3f44;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
}

#chevronDown:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #3c3f44;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
}

#chevronUp:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #3c3f44;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  }​

#chevronDown:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #3c3f44;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -35deg);
}
```

I thought this would be relatively simple, but I kept ending up with the downward facing chevron missing the right half, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3yqhhxc/1/

You can see it on the jsfiddle, there's a pesky little zero-width space character hanging out after closing bracket on the `#chevronUp:after` selector (on the `#chevronDown:after` closing bracket too).

Turns out these things are tough to delete.

I'm using Sublime Text 2 and found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356784/delete-u200b-zero-width-space-characters-using-sublime-text-3) on SO which worked, but I have no desire to have my text editor running an extra plugin after every keystroke.

So I tried some hacky behavior and ended up with this, which works, I'm assuming, by removing the zero-width space from affecting the selector following it:

```css
#chevronUp:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #3c3f44;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 35deg);
  }​{}   <------Note the extra brackets
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfm9c5fz/

But there's got to be a better answer than that? Where are these zero-width spaces being added/how do I stop it?

Comment: Looked like there was a newline artifact showing up in your jsfiddle CSS syntax.  I removed it and forked this one... http://jsfiddle.net/1ffrazka/... try it out.

Comment: What zero-width spaces? How do you see a zero-width thing? Describe what you see as the actual problem, instead of inventing names for it, and reduce the issue to a smaller case, e.g. remove all CSS that is not essential to producing the issue. And add relevant HTML.

Comment: Totally see what you mean (I see a little red circle in FF, btw). But this seems to be a problem with your text editor rather than CSS, can you try re-installing a fresh copy? Maybe using some faulty plugin? Also, I have found people from Sweden complaining at SublimeText forum about this same behavior, is that your case?

Comment: @Jukka, you see it as a little red circle in both the jsfiddle and on Chrome Developer tools. I also don't believe it's an invented name, considering that I just spent a fair amount of time looking into them, but I'm open to being corrected. The relevant html is only an empty div and is easily evident on the fiddle. I apologize if the question wasn't detailed enough.

Comment: @Lowkase, thanks, yeah I was able to spot the artifact as well and remove it on the fiddle, but wasn't able to get it removed in the code and it was consistently there when I ran the code or copied and pasted into, well, anywhere.

Comment: @Fabio, that was my among my first thoughts, did a fresh install, checked through the settings, disabled most of my plugins, no difference. The solution I reference in the question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356784/delete-u200b-zero-width-space-characters-using-sublime-text-3, but that seems like a poor workaround

Comment: @Fabio, missed the forum part of your comment, not finding what you're referencing when I search their forums, maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: sure, see https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9607 , but there are no answers to this either. However, they seem to be describing your exact issue and maybe some day someone will answer

Comment: Yeah, looks like it may be the same issue, thanks for that. Very odd, and to make it more interesting, it also looks like Notepad++ is doing the same thing when I rewrite it in there, which basically leaves me as confused I was before, wonderful.

Comment: @Rocky I wrote the answer in the question you linked, and I've just updated it to add an asynchronous ST3-specific version. Since the plugin running the `U+200B` search is now in a different thread, it shouldn't affect your typing speed or the performance of the main thread at all. Give it a try, and let me know what you think. Just FYI, there are already a few built-in plugins (and more if you've installed a bunch of packages) running event listeners, so one more shouldn't drastically change things. I haven't done any performance testing, but my revised plugin shouldn't change things much.

Comment: @Matt, that is fantastic, it works perfectly for me, and I don't notice any performance issues at all(referring to the ST3 version). A big thank you. I can't upvote the other answer or much else because of my lacking reputation, but if you want to answer here, I can mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Rocky I added the answer below. Please note that I changed the code slightly so that `U+200B` is now highlighted in the more visible `invalid` scope, instead of `string`, so any instances are much easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Sublime Text 3-specific plugin that runs asynchronously, looking for instances of zero-width spaces (Unicode code point `\u200b`). Every time the current view is modified, it searches through it character by character looking for the zero-width space character. If it finds one, it adds the location to a list and keeps looking until it reaches the end of the file. Then, if any characters were found, they are highlighted according to the `invalid` scope in your theme. Once highlighted, they can be selected and deleted. Since it runs asynchronously, you shouldn't see any performance drop while editing.

Open a new file in Sublime, and set its syntax to Python. Paste the following into it:

```py
import sublime_plugin

class ShowZeroWidthSpace(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified_async(self, view):
        spaces = []
        p = 0
        while True:
            s = view.find('\u200b', p + 1)
            if not s:
                break
            spaces.append(s)
            p = s.a

        if spaces:
            view.add_regions("zero-width", spaces, "invalid")
        else:
            view.erase_regions("zero-width")
```

Save the file in your `Packages/User` directory as `show_zero_width_space.py`, and it should start working immediately. You can find your `Packages` directory by selecting the **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** menu option.

---

Once you've determined that your file contains `U+200B` characters, you can easily get rid of them by using regex find and replace. Select **`Find -> Replace...`**, and in the "Find What" field enter `\x{200b}`. Leave the "Replace With" field blank, then select the `.*` Regular Expression button, the Wrap button, and the Highlight Matches button:

[image: U+200B]

Hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> and you're all set.