# What is this invisible character?

Tags: string, sublimetext, sublimetext3, invisible

I have strings in my code that contain invisible characters. look at the string below, the invisible characters is between the m and the last double quote.

I would like to know
a) what is it?
b) how to detect these?

I've tried both "draw_white_space": "all" in preferences and the plugn [TrailingSpaces](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces#installation) but they do not reveal them.

```
"com﻿"
```

Comment: How do you *know* you have "invisible characters" if you can't see them?

Comment: Two ways: 1) If I paste it in a text editor (like Sublime) and set the cursor at the end of the word and stepping left, it needs two "stepping left" to pass by the double quote and the m. 2) If pasting the string in the console, the cursor is not immediately after the string, there's a space inbetween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invisible character is Unicode [`U+FEFF - ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm). I've written a [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357538/1426065) to find and highlight zero-width characters. For your case, replace `'\u200b'` with `'\ufeff'` in the linked code and you should be all set. If one or more of those characters are in your text, they will be highlighted with the `invalid` scope (example using [`Neon Color Scheme`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) and [`IPython`](http://ipython.org) running in [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL)):

[image]

(note the dark red line after the `m`).